# Hide scroll bar but scroll with parent div

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax header for my wordpress site, i'm using the divi theme.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div class="parallax">
<div class="parralax__layer parallax__layer--back">
    <img src="https://crispimages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/layer_5.png">
  </div>>
<div class="parralax__layer parallax__layer--base">
    <img src="https://crispimages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/layer_5.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 25vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
transform: translateZ(-15px) scale(2);
}
```

My problem is that my header has this seperate scroll bar because it's in its over DIV to the rest of my page, the parallax effect works fine with overflow set to auto, but when I turn it off it breaks the paralax effect.

How do I get the header element to scroll with the rest of my page while still keeping the overflow set to auto?

You can see the problem I'm having here:
https://crispimages.co/home/

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following style rule:

```
.parallax::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

This will solve your problem. But as you can see its vendor prefix dependent. So it will only work in webkit browsers.

Comment: That's great and hides the scroll bar! However I still have 2 seperate scrolling sections that scroll independant of each other. I want the paralax div to scroll with my main scroll bar.